# Not Match Between Argument Passed and List Available

Tags: python

I was working with Python3, and trying some sorts of code. And then i came to try some function features, here is my code

```
def print_list_members(some_list):
    for i in first_list:
        print(i)
```

that's all my function definition. and then i add for example new to the code

```
first_list = ["Alfried", "Michael", "John"]
second_list = ["Joseph", "Tim", "Delta"]
```

then i try to produce traceback by passing different argument with the function code

```
print_list_members(second_list)
```

but, no traceback raised, except something make me a bit confused, the output is

```
Alfried
Michael
John
```

the question is, how it be possible? or is it an error from python itself?

Comment: you iterate over `first_list` inside the body of the function, so you print `first_list`. Whatever you pass as an argument is ignored. Perhaps you wanted iterate over `some_list`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what confuses you... What do you mean by *i try to produce traceback*? Are you trying to deliberately produce an error or do you simply mean to print the list?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code here

```
def print_list_members(some_list): 
    for i in some_list:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over the global `first_list` inside the body of the function, so you print `first_list`. Whatever you pass as an argument is ignored. Perhaps you wanted iterate over `some_list`?